# Is there anyway to get android app's crash log from other applications?

Tags: android, logging, service, crash

I know that there's ACRA (Application Crash Report for Android) or other ways to get a specific app crash log. But I want to do a service that listen should ANY apps on Android crashes, and if any app crashes, I want to know its package or name.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can read the logcat and trigger if a exception is logged.

Comment: How can i do that? Can you show me a code?